# I am getting empty array when the requestResponse is empty in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Here is my aggregation query:

```
    Request.aggregate([{
        $lookup: {
          from: "users",
          localField: "postedBy",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "postedBy",
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "users",
          localField: "assignedTo",
          foreignField: "username",
          as: "assignedTo",
        },
      },
      {$lookup: {
          from: "request_responses",
          let: {requestResponse: "$requestResponse"},
          pipeline: [{
              $match: {$expr: {$in: ["$_id", "$$requestResponse"]}}},
            {$lookup: {
                from: "users",
                let: {postedBy: "$postedBy"},
                pipeline: [{$match: {$expr: {$eq: ["$_id", "$$postedBy"]}}}, ],
                as: "postedBy"
              }},
            {$unwind: '$postedBy'}
          ],
          as: "requestResponse",},},
      {$unwind: '$postedBy',},
      {$unwind: '$assignedTo'},
      {
        $project: {
          status: 1,
          requestResponse: {
            response: 1,
            postedBy: {
              type: 1,
              firstname: 1,
              lastname: 1,
              username: 1
            },
          },
          subject: 1,
          topic: 1,
          request: 1,
          severity: 1,
          postedBy: {
            type: 1,
            firstname: 1,
            lastname: 1,
            username: 1
          },
          assignedTo: {
            type: 1,
            firstname: 1,
            lastname: 1,
            username: 1
          }
        }
      }
    ])
```

I have used node.js and mongodb in my project and while doing it I am using lookup instead of populate because I'm using the username instead of objectId for the postedBy and assignedTo. So for I have tried populating the document using lookup. requestResponse is an array of response. When it is empty the result I get are also empty even though the requests exist. But if the requestResponse is not empty then I get the results of only documents having the requestResponse as not empty. How do I apply not empty condition in the lookup for requestResponse.

[Image of the respone from postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FI1M7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

```
{
        $unwind: {
          path: '$assignedTo',
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
      },
```

this did the trick.